# TCPDF: wrong page count

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm creating a PDF with a custom header and footer but, I don't understand why, when I add an image in the footer, the total page count gets busted and added twice:

```
$logoFileName = 'images/image.png';
$logoX = 0; // 0mm
$logoY = $this->GetY()-10; // 0mm
$logoWidth = 200; // 15mm
$logo = 'Pagina ' . $this->getAliasNumPage() . '/' . $this->getAliasNbPages() . $this->Image($logoFileName, $logoX, $logoY, $logoWidth);

// $this->SetX($this->w - $this->documentRightMargin - $logoWidth);
$this->Cell(0,10, $logo, 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
```

Results:

- [first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEV6u.png)
- [second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzcJH.png)

With same script, if I delete `this->image()` the count is correct.

I also add that, if I remove the following function from the script:

```
$this->getAliasNbPages()
```

so it becomes so:

```
$logo = 'Pagina ' . $this->getAliasNumPage() . '/' . $this->Image($logoFileName, $logoX, $logoY, $logoWidth);
```

the first page is correct masculine but the following ones are correct:

[first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvafG.png)
[second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMtAx.png)

Comment: Maybe your image actually ads 30 pages?

Comment: what is the work of this function : $logoY = $this->GetY()-10; ??? may be some data came twice ...

Comment: $logoY = $this->GetY()-10; set Y margin at the bottom of page. No, is not this the problem.

Comment: You're creating a string `$logo` by concatenating an image to it. An image is not a string. The `3` you see it just coincidental, it could have been anything.

Comment: Is not correct; if you see the source code of TCPDF you can see thath function "image" return a string.

Comment: I tried to look up the documentation, but I couldn't find what `image()` returns. Do you have the URL? Or can you say what is returned? (a string containing what?)

Comment: Instead of trying to put an `image` which is a `cell` couldn't you just write the image after your cell by getting the current XY after writing your cell ? `$logoX = $this->getX();`

Comment: I checked the source code, and `Image()` can return a lot: Nothing, `false`, an object, etc.